# Como pegar arquivo de dentro do banco de dados?

Tags: php, pdo, postgresql, arquivo

Estou usando o postgresql como sgdb, e estou salvando arquivos .txt no bd, até aí, tudo certo, ja está funcionando certo, mas não estou achando uma forma pra pegar o conteudo dos arquivos txt salvos no bd, estou usando php com PDO pra conexão ao bd

O tipo da coluna que salva txt no banco é OID, que armazena um large_object

estou salvando assim o arquivo txt no banco:

```
session_start();
require 'database.php';

$n_documento    = (!empty($_POST['documento']))     ? $_POST['documento']       : '';
$n_capitulo     = (!empty($_POST['capitulo']))      ? $_POST['capitulo']        : '';
$titulo         = isset($_POST['titulo'])           ? $_POST['titulo']          : '';
$paragrafo      = isset($_POST['valor_paragrafo'])  ? $_POST['valor_paragrafo'] : '';

$fp = fopen("capitulo_$n_capitulo.txt", "w+");
$conteudo = fwrite($fp, $paragrafo);
fclose($fp);
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE capitulos SET
                paragrafo = lo_import('C:/wamp/www/crud/capitulo_$n_capitulo.txt'),
                titulo = $titulo
            WHERE id_documento = $n_documento
                  AND n_capitulo = $n_capitulo";
    $pdo->query($sql);
    Database::disconnect();
}
```

como eu faço pra pegar esse txt que salvei? tanto faz a forma, seja pelo sql ou por php.

Comment: Você ta salvando o caminho para o arquivo? ao o conteúdo? pelo que notei é o caminho, pode confirmar? | A variável `$conteudo` é usada onde?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não, não estou salvando o caminho, salvo só o arquivo, normalmente; mas qual seria a importancia de salvar o caminho? visto que o arquivo esta em minha maquina e vai ser acessado por qq pessoa online?

Comment: Não justamente isso, deve se salvar o conteúdo, pelo que eu vi achei que você estava salvando a caminho, ai não resultaria em no que você quer. Essa coluna é de que tipo? você verificou no pgadmin se ela esta populada?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert a coluna é do tipo oid, é um tipo usado pra large objects, basicamente é um número que referencia o arquivo, que fica guardado num lugar separado da database do sistema em si, e o código que coloquei aí está fncionando certinho, só coloquei aí na tentativa de fazer entenderem a dinamica do que preciso

Comment: o que preciso de fato é exportar o conteudo desse arquivo salvo no bd